# What is the meaning of "a==('a' or 'b')" at Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logical-operators

Look at this code at Python:

```
a='a'
print(a==('a' or 'b'))
a='b'
print(a==('a' or 'b'))
```

The output will be:

```
True
False
```

Can you explain me why please?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you check what `'a' or 'b'` evaluated to?

Comment: This will probably soon be closed as a duplicate, even though it's hard to find via search. The answer is in the way the `or` operator works, look it up in the documentation.

Comment: Try `print('a' or 'b')`

Comment: Now I see, thank you!!

Comment: Have you tried using | instead of or - (| = pipe) https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_basic_operators.htm

Comment: @SCramphorn did you? `'a' | 'b'` is an error. In general, `|` (bitwise or) has a rather different purpose to `or` (logical or), and can give very different result, meaning that suggesting it as a drop-in replacement is rarely helpful outside of situations like numpy arrays filled with bools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To break it down, The parenthesis get evaluated first.
So, `"a" or "b"` - "a" is truthy and returns itself. "b" never gets evaluated because a non empty string will always be truthy.

To get a better idea of this, run it by itself in a prompt

```
>>> ('a' or 'b') 
'a'
```

Thus you end up with `'a' == 'a'` - which is true

IN the second example, a is set to 'b' so the same thing happens, only 'b' ≠ 'a' so it returns false

Answer (score 2):

@rm-vanda is correct.

I believe the behavior you expect is better found using lists or tuples:

```
>>> a = "b"
>>> a in ["a", "b"]
True
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have an expression like `'a' or 'b'`, it will return the first value that is not `False`. That being said, in both cases the expression will return `'a'`.

I assume you can figure out the rest of it on your own, but the first is `True` because you equate `'a' == 'a'`, and in the second `'b' == 'a'`.

Comment: _that is not `None`_, didn't you mean _that is not `False`_?

Comment: "not `None`" is a little bit inaccurate. There are lots of other values besides `None` that will fail too.

Comment: Correction made

Comment: "not `False`" isn't accurate either. The truth is more complicated and subtle.

Comment: `''` is "not `False`", but check what `'' or 'b'` gives you. The rule is actually whether the LHS is *truthy* - ie, whether `bool(LHS)` is True (and strings, like other builtin sequences and containers, are truthy exactly when they are nonempty). Also, note that `x or y` only ever checks the truthiness of `x` - if it is truthy, the result is `x`, otherwise it is `y`.

Answer (score 0):

`('a' or 'b')` will always resolve as `'a'` because `'a'` is resolved as `True` in a boolean context.

`x or y` returns the value of `x` if `x` is True (= different of `None`, `False`, `""`, `(,)`, `[]` or `{}`), else it returns the value of `y`.